# How do I display Scala 2.12.0-M5 -opt:help using sbt console?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a bug using with scala 2.12.0-M5 -opt:help & sbt 0.13.12-RC1?
I raise the question because both are beta software & now is the time to
report bugs.

When I use -opt:help with standalone scala 2.12.0-M5 (linux Ubuntu 16.04)
I get a nice printout of scala optimizer options & scala exits back to the
command line.

When I attempt to do the same thing by setting scalacOptions in build.sbt
and executing the "console" command, sbt 0.13.12-RC1 appears to ignore the option (no printout, nothing in :settings) and leaves me at an active  "scala> " prompt.

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-opt:help"
)


> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M5 (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :settings
-Yrepl-sync = true
-d = .
-nowarn = false
??? I expect to see a -opt line here
```

Setting -opt:l:classpath works as I would expect:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-opt:l:classpath"
)

> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M5 (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :settings
-Yrepl-sync = true
-d = .
-nowarn = false
-opt = optChoices.ValueSet(unreachable-code, simplify-jumps, 
compact-locals, copy-propagation, redundant-casts, box-unbox, 
nullness-tracking, closure-invocations, inline-project, inline-global)
```

Am I missing something obvious or is there a bug here?

Thank you,

Lee

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to a specific pre-release version of two software artefacts in conjunction. It should be reported as a bug on one or both of those project issue trackers. It is not a general programming question which has an answer that is meaningful outside of this very specific context.

Comment: @MilesSabin Perhaps OP was too hasty in concluding this is an issue specific to sbt 0.13.12-RC1 or a bug at all. I just tried using sbt 0.13.11, and still encounter the same behavior. We can easily edit the above into a "How can I do X in sbt?" question.